# Dynamic geotargeting on a carrd landing page?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am having issues with geotargeting on my cardd landing page. I am using snoopi.io API key.

Firstly, the location of the user's location is displayed in the wrong section of the site (top left, which is incorrect).

Secondly, it doesn't seem to be pulling the user's location.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64KgI.png)

The code that I am using is based on a 4 year old youtube vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KiGKd2XXL4

I have no coding experience so, I tried to clean up the code via chatgpt but with no luck.

I have embedded two pieces of code within the page:

Hidden - Head of site

```
<p id="location">Loading location data...</p>

<!-- Add this script in the custom code section of your carrd.com page -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Function to handle the API response and update the HTML
    function handleApiResponse(json) {
      if (json && json.City && json.State) {
        // Concatenate the location data with the additional text
        var locationText = json.City + ', ' + json.State + ' - 4.8 miles away';
        $('#location').html(locationText);
      } else {
        $('#location').html('Location data not available');
      }
    }

    var apiKey = 'MY API KEY';

    // Make the AJAX call to Snoopi API
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.snoopi.io/check',
      data: { apikey: apiKey },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'handleApiResponse',
      error: function() {
        $('#location').html('Error occurred while fetching data');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Hidden - Body Top

```
<input type="text" id="locationTextBox" />
```

Comment: Part of debugging code is to understand your available tools. Browsers have a built-in developer tool which you can access by pressing F12. It has a number of tabs. The one you need right now is "network". With the tool open refresh the page and watch the logs appear in the tab. What do they say? Any error numbers/messages?